# How to inject snippets of html into an string containing valid html?

Tags: java, html, xml, jsoup

I have the following html (sized down for literary content) that is passed into a java method.

However, I want to take this passed in html string and add a <pre> tag that contains some text passed in and add a section of <script type="text/javascript"> to the head.

```
String buildHTML(String htmlString, String textToInject)
{
  // Inject inject textToInject into pre tag and add javascript sections
  String newHTMLString = <build new html sections>
}
```

-- htmlString --

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <body>
</html>
```

-- newHTMLString

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function(){alert("hello?";}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="1">
        <pre>
          <!-- Inject textToInject here into a newly created pre tag-->
        </pre>
     </div>
  <body>
</html>
```

What is the best tool to do this from within java other than a regex?

Comment: HTML or XHTML? If the latter you can do this with a standard XML library.

Comment: @nablex: html but i think some other type of xml parse would work?  possibly jsoup as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do this with **Jsoup**:

```
public String buildHTML(String htmlString, String textToInject)
{
    // Create a document from string
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

    // create the script tag in head
    doc.head().appendElement("script")
            .attr("type", "text/javascript")
            .text("window.onload=function(){alert(\'hello?\';}");


    // Create div tag
    Element div = doc.body().appendElement("div").attr("id", "1");

    // Create pre tag
    Element pre = div.appendElement("pre");
    pre.text(textToInject);

    // Return as string
    return doc.toString();
}
```

I've used *chaining* a lot, what means:

```
doc.body().appendElement(...).attr(...).text(...)
```

is exactly the same as

```
Element example = doc.body().appendElement(...);
example.attr(...);
example.text(...);
```

**Example:**

```
final String html = "<html>\n"
        + "  <head>\n"
        + "  </head>\n"
        + "  <body>\n"
        + "  <body>\n"
        + "</html>";

String result = buildHTML(html, "This is a test.");

System.out.println(result);
```

**Result:**

```
<html>
 <head> 
  <script type="text/javascript">window.onload=function(){alert('hello?';}</script>
 </head> 
 <body>  
  <div id="1">
   <pre>This is a test.</pre>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```